# How to identify a client with nodejs/express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am creating a web app that offers a membership access with a trial period. However, I need to be sure the users cannot create a new account with other credentials just to get another trial period and so on.

I was considering using `req.connection.remoteAddress;` to know if a client already claimed its trial but I am not sure this ip address will be unique to a specific machine.

Any idea ?

Comment: You know why free trials still need your credit card?

Comment: Yeah but today with online banks you can use virtual credit card that you can remove right after.

Comment: Well, then done other non-duplicatable info then. There isn't a sure way to tell users. Coded values are easily spoofed...